# Inserting line breaks into python dictionary definitions?

Tags: python

Please pardon me for any mistakes, as this is my first time posting here, and I don't code in Python.

I'm trying to edit an InkScape extension, and in it they have a piece of code (What I believe is the Dictionary?) that adds lines before and after the blocks of GCode.

Seen here:

```
self.tools = {
    "name": "Laser Engraver",
    "id": "Laser Engraver",
    "penetration feed": self.options.laser_speed,
    "feed": self.options.laser_speed,
    "gcode before path": ("G0 Z0.1"),
    "gcode after path": ("G0 F" + self.options.travel_speed),
}
```

I'd like the piece of code the part where it prints the travel speed (What I believe is the Definition?):

```
"gcode after path": ("G0 F" + self.options.travel_speed),
```

To also print a new line that says "G0 Z5"

My question is how do I go about doing this.

Would I add it after separated by commas as in:

```
"gcode after path": ("G0 F" + self.options.travel_speed),("G0 Z5"),
```

Or do I use \n in the middle as in:

```
"gcode after path": ("G0 F" + self.options.travel_speed \n "G0 Z5"),
```

Or do I Semi-Colon the two as in:

```
"gcode after path": ("G0 F" + self.options.travel_speed);("G0 Z5"),
```

Or is there some other way that I haven't found yet?

A little clarification, the output currently looks like this:

```
G0 Z0.1
G0 X-69.535 Y-75.5701
G0 F3000

G0 Z0.1
G1 X-69.4779 Y-75.4004F200.000000
G1 X-69.3627 Y-75.3433
G1 X-69.23 Y-75.2775
G0 F3000
```

I'm looking for it to be this instead:

```
G0 Z0.1
G0 X-69.535 Y-75.5701
G0 F3000
G0 Z5

G0 Z0.1
G1 X-69.4779 Y-75.4004F200.000000
G1 X-69.3627 Y-75.3433
G1 X-69.23 Y-75.2775
G0 F3000
G0 Z5
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like the value for each key is supposed to be a single string. `"gcode after path": ("G0 F" + self.options.travel_speed + "\nG0 Z5"),`

Comment: Why don't you just try all the things you're guessing about to see what happens? Much quicker than posting a question and waiting for answers.

Comment: It's a matter of importing the extension every time, opening the program, saving an output, every time.

Comment: @Galen that worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

None of the alternatives you outlined will work - all three are syntax errors.

The simple way to put a line break in a string is by including a newline. Assuming `self.options.travel_speed` is a string at this point in your code, something like:

```
'gcode after path': 'G0 F' + self.options.travel_speed + '\nG0 Z5'
```

More generally, you can separate lists or tuples of strings with newlines via:

```
'gcode after path': '\n'.join('G0 F' + self.options.travel_speed, 'G0 Z5', something_else)
```

I'm not familiar with your application, so you may have to convert `speed` to a string first.

Comment: You need an extra set of parens or brackets in your `join` code; `join` takes a single iterable, not varargs. Either `'\n'.join(['G0 F' + self.options.travel_speed, 'G0 Z5', something_else])` (temporary `list`) or `'\n'.join(('G0 F' + self.options.travel_speed, 'G0 Z5', something_else))` (temporary `tuple`) would work.

Comment: The first block is just copy and pasted directly from the code. It works fine as is. the travel speed is set by the user but it's a number (3000).

Comment: The output looks something like this:

`G0 Z0.1<Gcode before Path
G1 X-69.4779 Y-75.4004F200.000000
G1 X-69.3627 Y-75.3433
G1 X-69.23 Y-75.2775
G0 F3000 <Gcode after path`

Comment: if you are using "join', no need to concatenate components with "+". It should use either format or f-strings anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As Galen as Chris Johnson said, 
Changing the definition to look like this:

```
"gcode after path": ("G0 F" + self.options.travel_speed + "\nG0 Z5"),
```

Gave me the desired output of :

```
G0 Z0.1 < Before Path
G0 F200.000000
G1 X105.6317 Y96.7619 < Path
G1 X105.6317 Y45.9619 < Path
G1 X65.3143 Y45.9619 < Path
G1 X65.3143 Y96.7619 < Path
G0 F3000 < After Path
G0 Z0.5 < After Path
G0 X49.9936 Y225.7778
G0 Z0.1
G0 F200.000000
G1 X137.8857 Y225.7778
G1 X137.8857 Y141.9175
G1 X49.9936 Y141.9175
G1 X49.9936 Y225.7778
G0 F3000
G0 Z0.5
```

Thank you everyone for the help!